# Как создать плавную анимацию перехода между страницами сайта?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли это сделать только через css и html, или с добавлением js?
Мне нужна анимация, когда я нажимаю на какую-либо ссылку или кнопку, которая ведет на следующую html страницу сайта, и в это время идет плавная анимация перехода.
Например блюр сайта при переходе.

Comment: https://s-sd.ru/blog_studio_design/plavnaya_smena_stranic_s_pomoshchyu_jquery/ примерно такой механизм

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно сделать. К примеру на серверной стороне, для страниц у которых `url` адресс заканчиваеться на `/page2/` добавлять для тега `<body class="animated">`, если же у вас `SPA` тоже есть решения, возможно там у вас не загрузка новой страницы, а обновления контента...
Вообщем ответ - да. Дальше уже смотреть от вашего сайта, это задача над которой надо посидеть, но решения в интернете уже есть.

Comment: Во времена, когда повсеместно царствовал IE, был в нём такой метатег [RevealTrans](http://www.influentialcomputers.co.uk/meta-reveal-demo.asp) . Вот начинающим раздолье было - вставил тег и готов переход с эффектами между страницами :-)